# Inject MongDb with unity depencendy injection

Tags: c#, mongodb, dependency-injection, unity-container

So far I have the following code in my Repository:

```
public MyRepo(ILog logger)
{
    this.Logger = logger;

    var mongoUrlBuilder = new MongoUrlBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyContext"].ConnectionString);
    this.MongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoUrlBuilder.ToMongoUrl());
    this.MongoDatabase = this.MongoClient.GetDatabase("MyDB");
    this.UserCollection = this.MongoDatabase.GetCollection<MyModel>("pro");
}
```

And this is how I use unity DI container for instance :

```
var container = new UnityContainer();

container.RegisterType<IMyModel, MyModel>();

RegisterTypes(container);
return container;
```

How can use unity DI to inject MongoDb?

The main reason I am asking is because I want to be able to mock mongoDb and do testing on it. The requirements ask me to use Unity DI and MongoDb.

**UPDATE**

Eventually I went with the following patern. I Added a Db context class that look like this:

```
public class MongoDbContext
    {
        public const string CONNECTION_STRING_NAME = "DBContext";
        public const string DATABASE_NAME = "MyDb";

        private static readonly IMongoClient Client;
        private static readonly IMongoDatabase Database;

        static MongoDbContext()
        {
            var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[CONNECTION_STRING_NAME].ConnectionString;
            Client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
            Database = Client.GetDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
        }

        public IMongoCollection<TEntity> GetCollection<TEntity>()
        {
            return Database.GetCollection<TEntity>(typeof(TEntity).Name.ToLower() + "s");
        }
    }
```

And inside the MongoRepository use it like this:

```
      public class MyRepository<TModel> : IGenericMongoRepository<TModel> where TModel : BaseModel
        {
            private MongoDbContext MongoDbContext = null;

            public Exception OperationException { get; set; }
            private ILog Logger;

            public MyRepository(ILog logger)
            {
                this.Logger = logger;
                this.MongoDbContext = new MongoDbContext();
            }
      public async Task<TModel> Add(TModel item)      
        {
            try
            {
                IMongoCollection<TModel> collection = this.GetCollection<TModel>();
                await collection.InsertOneAsync(item);
                return item;
            }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wy not using repository pattern and abstracts the logic in a reposiotory

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel Could I get an example? "MyRepo" implements an interface which I am injecting in other places which use this CRUD logic inside MyRepo.

Comment: So why you need to Inject MongoDb that does not make much sense AFAK

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor the repo to take the mongo database as an injectable dependency

```
private IMongoDatabase database;
private ILog Logger;
private IMongoCollection<MyModel> UserCollection;

public MyRepo(ILog logger, IMongoDatabase database) {
    this.Logger = logger;
    this.database = database;
    this.UserCollection = database.GetCollection<MyModel>("pro");
}
```

then the creation of the instance can be moved to the composition root

```
//Create the database instance
var mongoUrlBuilder = new MongoUrlBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyContext"].ConnectionString);
var client = new MongoClient(mongoUrlBuilder.ToMongoUrl());
var database = client.GetDatabase("MyDB");

var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IMyModel, MyModel>();
// Register existing object instance
container.RegisterInstance<IMongoDatabase>(database);

RegisterTypes(container);
return container;
```

Comment: Ok but I think you are a bit away from the repository pattern goals

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel, While the OP mentions a repository doesn't necessary mean that they are applying the repository pattern. I simply wanted to demonstrate that MongoDb already provides abstractions to allow for injections and testability based on OP requirements.

Comment: I was thinking about this option, however I think that all the components that help to inject the MongoDatabase, should not belong in unity class or be as well injected in some way and configured.

Comment: @Mr.Sarunov then move it to its own class. You will still however have to pass the instance to the container some how.